# React Native TextInput: can the underline length be set?

Tags: react-native

Any idea if the length of the underline of TextInput can be defined to be at a given length, independently of the placeholder length and the typed input length?

Comment: What do you mean with the underline of a textInput?

Comment: The underline color is set by underlineColorAndroid: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#underlinecolorandroid
I want to set the length

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer while trying to change something else...

If width is set for TextInput, the size of the underline is set to that width (maxLength, that is specified below, doesn't affect that):

```
<TextInput
    style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'black',
        width: 270, paddingLeft: 0 }}
    placeholder='type text here...'
    underlineColorAndroid='#888'
    value={this.state.password}
    onChangeText={(text) =>
        this.onPasswordChange(text)}
    editable = {true}
    maxLength = {10}
/>
```